# URL Rewriting doesn't seem to work. Apache2

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-modules

I would like it so that when the user goes to
`http://mysite.com/home` that it redirects him to `http://mysite.com/page.php?id=home`. This is what I put in my .htaccess, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

It just sends me to the /home directory, with a nice 404. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

I've tried some rewrite I know work, so now I'm certain it's not that my problem. I checked with `phpinfo()` and yes, mod rewrite is running, I set up apache2 with LAMP, I'm running the latest version of Linux Mint.

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok well I fixed the problem, this is how I did it.

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

and then I modified `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride all` in the `/var/www/` part of the file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all #This was 'None' before, change it to 'all'
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart Apache after this!

Comment: Thank you!  I had similar problem and Your solution helped me.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me after removing the forward slash:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /test 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: is page.php in your document root? if you are not in the document root directory you will also need to add a RewriteBase statement

Comment: edited my answer showing you my .htaccess file. Hope this helps!