# Redirect requests with .htaccess to api.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've created a folder api/ in my www/html folder.. I've put a .htaccess file in there that looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

In the api/ folder I have the api.php file with this code for testing;

```
<?php

echo $_REQUEST['request'];

?>
```

If I go to myserver/api/test I get a 404 not found.. So in this case I would thing it should echo test?

I've also tried putting the file in the www/html file instead of inside the api folder since I specify the api folder in the .htaccess file..

Comment: Sure you got mod_rewrite enabled in the first place? Remove the ifmodule check, and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Still getting the same 404.. should the file be under api/ or in the base folder?

Comment: If I try to go to myserver/api/api.php directly I get a 500 error

Comment: Then check the relevant log files to find out why ...

Comment: I actually had some failing php in the php file I had there.. I striped it out to have just what I posted above.. and I can go to myserver/api/api.php now.. but still I cannot do myserver/api/test to get it to output "test".. I have the .htaccess file in base folder..

Comment: php_info() says mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `AllowOverride All` in my `apache2.conf` file

Reference this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662459/7417114